# What is the most efficient way to use sidebar menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So if I have to make a sidebar menu like schools websites, in which active clicked link is highlighted after the page loads. It uses individual pages like

```
<a target="_top" href="default.asp">HTML HOME</a>
<a target="_top" href="html_intro.asp">HTML Introduction</a>
<a target="_top" href="html_editors.asp">HTML Editors</a>
<a target="_top" href="html_basic.asp">HTML Basic</a>
<a target="_top" href="html_elements.asp">HTML Elements</a>
```

But the one I built on my own is created with PHP so what happens in that one is the title or name of menu item is changed to lowercase and saved in database in same row called class which is used for active link highlighting. So what happens when sidebar link is clicked is only content of summary div's content
(which is right to the sidebar) is changed while sidebar and navigation bar stays same. So it stays on the same page and retrieves data from database and puts in summary div.

```
<body class='noPadding'>
     <div class='bigNav'>             <!-- top navbar -->
          <img src="images/logo2.png"/>
     </div>

     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['subject'])){
         $subject=$_GET['subject'];


     ?>
     <div class='container'>
        <div class='leftLayout' style='padding-top:70px;background-color:#EBEBEB'>
            <ul class="fullFit">
              <?php
                 $query="SELECT * FROM `study` WHERE `subject`='$subject'";
                 $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                       $topic=$row['topic'];
                       $class=$row['class'];  ?>

                             <li  class="<?php echo $class?>">
                               <a href='<?php echo $sitename ?>/web.php?subject=<?php echo $subject?>&topic=<?php echo $class?>'>
                                   <?php echo $topic?>
                               </a>
                             </li>

                  <?php  }  ?>

            </ul>
        </div>

     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['topic'])) {
         $active_id=$_GET['topic'];
         $topic=$_GET['topic'];
         $query="SELECT summary FROM `study` WHERE `class`='$active_id'";
         $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
         $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
         $summary=$row[0];
      ?>
        <div class='summary'> <?php echo $summary ?> </div>
      <?php } ?>


     </div>
  <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".<?php echo $active_id ?>").addClass("current");
        });

  </script>

<?php  }  ?>

</body>
```

And also if I have to make individual pages instead like many websites including W3Schools does, do I have to create a new file each time and include navigation bar and sidebar(which are supposed to stay same on every link) in each file?
How do they manage it?

Comment: I recommend [including](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [requiring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) files. For example, "HTML Editors" in the navigation might link to `index.php?page=editors`. In your `index.php` file, include an `editors.php` content file based on that `page` variable. Then you won't need to repeat the main site structure (header, navigation, etc) in every file. You might find this article informative: [Organize Your Next PHP Project the Right Way](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way--net-5873)

Comment: What I've described is known as a ["front controller" pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#front-controller). Depending on the complexity of your project, it might be simpler or more effective to make a separate file for each page (`intro.php`, `editors.php`, etc.) and include a universal `navigation.php` in each file. Also see examples in this post: [simple php websites structure](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/whats-the-best-approach-for-a-simple-php-websites-structure).

Comment: thank you for comment.so should i make individual files and include header in each file now?

Comment: and can you please also tell why the way i am doing is not recommended? thanks

Comment: Thats one simple example. The question might be too broad or opinion-based to effectively answer here. Can you tell us a little more about your site content? Are you calling each main section (intro, editors, basic) a "subject"? And does each subject contain multiple topics? And each topic has a summary?

Comment: yes,that is right. lets say if i am making a music tutorials then subjects are guitar,piano,violin and all these subjects have many topics like intro etc.and in database row i have topic and summary. when i click on topic it gets the summary and puts it in summary div

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is not too much of a departure from your current structure.
I don't intend to lead you down a rabbit hole.

That being said, it sounds like you could code everything into a single PHP file. Note that this is just one of many methods, highly dependent the scope of your project and individual coding style.

### Databases

**subject**

```
`id`
`name`
```

**topic**

```
`id`
`subject_id`
`name`
`summary`
```

### PHP

```
<?php

// define database functions

function getAllSubjects($conn) {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE 1;";
  $q=$conn->query($sql);
  return $q; 
}

function getSubject($conn,$subject_id=false) {
  $r=false;
  if (is_numeric($subject_id)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE `id`=?;";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->bind_param('i',$subject_id);
    $q->execute();
    $r=$q->fetch_assoc();
  }
  return $r;
}

function getSubjectTopics($conn,$subject_id=false) {
  $q=false;
  if (is_numeric($subject_id)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `topic` WHERE `subject_id`=?;";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->bind_param('i',$subject_id);
    $q->execute();
  }
  return $q;
}

function getTopic($conn,$topic_id=false) {
  $r=false;
  if (is_numeric($topic_id)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `topic` WHERE `id`=?;";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->bind_param('i',$topic_id);
    $q->execute();
    $r=$q->fetch_assoc();
  }
  return $r;
}


// get URL parameters

$subject_id = !empty($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])
  ? $_GET['s']
  : false;

$topic_id = !empty($_GET['t']) && is_numeric($_GET['t'])
  ? $_GET['t']
  : false;


// fetch all subjects from database
$subjectsQ=getAllSubjects($conn);

// fetch current subject
$thisSubject = $subject_id
  ? getSubject($conn,$subject_id)
  : false;

// fetch current subject topics
$thisSubjectTopicsQ = !empty($thisSubject)
  ? getSubjectTopics($conn,$subject_id)
  : false;

// fetch current topic
$thisTopic = $topic_id
  ? getTopic($conn,$topic_id)
  : false;


// display subject navigation
while($subject = $subjectsQ->fetch_assoc()){

  // determine if this subject is selected
  $sel = !empty($thisSubject) && $thisSubject['id']==$subject['id']
    ? true
    : false;

  // define the URL
  $url = '?s='.$subject['id'];

  // display nav item for this subject
  echo '<a href="' . $url . '"'
         . ($sel?' class="sel"' : '')
         . '>' . $subject['name']
         . '</a>';

}

// if there are subject topics to display...
if ($thisSubjectTopicsQ && $thisSubjectTopicsQ->num_rows > 0) {

  // loop through this subject's topics
  while($topic=$thisSubjectTopicsQ->fetch_assoc()){

    // determine if this topic is selected
    $sel = !empty($thisTopic) && $thisTopic['id']==$topic['id']
      ? true
      : false;

    // define the URL
    $url = '?s='.$thisSubject['id'].'&t='.$topic['id'];

    // display nav item for this topic
    // (alternate way to display the link)
    ?><a href="<?=$url?>"<?=$sel?' class="selected"':''?>><?php
      echo $topic['name'];
    ?></a><?php

  }

}

// if there is a topic to display
if (!empty($thisTopic)) {
  // display topic summary
  echo $thisTopic['summary'];
}
```

---

That's a basic example. Granted, it doesn't include any of the HTML structure.

It's also possible to join the two tables so that you don't need to do so much fetching. For example, fetching a topic could also return its subject:

```
$sql="SELECT s.`id` AS `subject_id,
             s.`name` AS `subject_name`,
             t.`id` AS `topic_id,
             t.`name` AS `topic_name`,
             t.`summary` AS `topic_summary`
      FROM `topic` t
      LEFT JOIN `subject` s ON (s.`id`=t.`subject_id`)
      WHERE t.`id`=?";
```

Comment: Is the downvote because I should not attempt to answer such a broad question? Or because I'm not answering the question about how to organize files? Or something else?